# JS console error while using function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is a simple question but i could not find out a solution for this.

I have error on debugging console, because of .placeholder function .

How do i fix it ?

Link to [Codepen](http://codepen.io/sabipu/pen/WrOQVW)

HTML

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your name">
```

JS

```
// Intializing placeholder 
(function($) {
    jQuery('input, textarea').placeholder();
}(jQuery));

/* HTML5 placeholder jQuery plugin - v2.3.0
 * Copyright (c)2015 Mathias Bynens
 * 2015-11-13
 */
!function(a){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],a):a("object"==typeof module&&module.exports?require("jquery"):jQuery)}(function(a){function b(b){var c={},d=/^jQuery\d+$/;return a.each(b.attributes,function(a,b){b.specified&&!d.test(b.name)&&(c[b.name]=b.value)}),c}function c(b,c){var d=this,f=a(this);if(d.value===f.attr(h?"placeholder-x":"placeholder")&&f.hasClass(n.customClass))if(d.value="",f.removeClass(n.customClass),f.data("placeholder-password")){if(f=f.hide().nextAll('input[type="password"]:first').show().attr("id",f.removeAttr("id").data("placeholder-id")),b===!0)return f[0].value=c,c;f.focus()}else d==e()&&d.select()}function d(d){var e,f=this,g=a(this),i=f.id;if(!d||"blur"!==d.type||!g.hasClass(n.customClass))if(""===f.value){if("password"===f.type){if(!g.data("placeholder-textinput")){try{e=g.clone().prop({type:"text"})}catch(j){e=a("<input>").attr(a.extend(b(this),{type:"text"}))}e.removeAttr("name").data({"placeholder-enabled":!0,"placeholder-password":g,"placeholder-id":i}).bind("focus.placeholder",c),g.data({"placeholder-textinput":e,"placeholder-id":i}).before(e)}f.value="",g=g.removeAttr("id").hide().prevAll('input[type="text"]:first').attr("id",g.data("placeholder-id")).show()}else{var k=g.data("placeholder-password");k&&(k[0].value="",g.attr("id",g.data("placeholder-id")).show().nextAll('input[type="password"]:last').hide().removeAttr("id"))}g.addClass(n.customClass),g[0].value=g.attr(h?"placeholder-x":"placeholder")}else g.removeClass(n.customClass)}function e(){try{return document.activeElement}catch(a){}}var f,g,h=!1,i="[object OperaMini]"===Object.prototype.toString.call(window.operamini),j="placeholder"in document.createElement("input")&&!i&&!h,k="placeholder"in document.createElement("textarea")&&!i&&!h,l=a.valHooks,m=a.propHooks,n={};j&&k?(g=a.fn.placeholder=function(){return this},g.input=!0,g.textarea=!0):(g=a.fn.placeholder=function(b){var e={customClass:"placeholder"};return n=a.extend({},e,b),this.filter((j?"textarea":":input")+"["+(h?"placeholder-x":"placeholder")+"]").not("."+n.customClass).not(":radio, :checkbox, :hidden").bind({"focus.placeholder":c,"blur.placeholder":d}).data("placeholder-enabled",!0).trigger("blur.placeholder")},g.input=j,g.textarea=k,f={get:function(b){var c=a(b),d=c.data("placeholder-password");return d?d[0].value:c.data("placeholder-enabled")&&c.hasClass(n.customClass)?"":b.value},set:function(b,f){var g,h,i=a(b);return""!==f&&(g=i.data("placeholder-textinput"),h=i.data("placeholder-password"),g?(c.call(g[0],!0,f)||(b.value=f),g[0].value=f):h&&(c.call(b,!0,f)||(h[0].value=f),b.value=f)),i.data("placeholder-enabled")?(""===f?(b.value=f,b!=e()&&d.call(b)):(i.hasClass(n.customClass)&&c.call(b),b.value=f),i):(b.value=f,i)}},j||(l.input=f,m.value=f),k||(l.textarea=f,m.value=f),a(function(){a(document).delegate("form","submit.placeholder",function(){var b=a("."+n.customClass,this).each(function(){c.call(this,!0,"")});setTimeout(function(){b.each(d)},10)})}),a(window).bind("beforeunload.placeholder",function(){var b=!0;try{"javascript:void(0)"===document.activeElement.toString()&&(b=!1)}catch(c){}b&&a("."+n.customClass).each(function(){this.value=""})}))});`enter code here
```

`

And one more thing, i need my function to be like so .

```
 (function($) {
    // codes
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: please add more details, providing your code would be usefull

Comment: show us what you tried

Comment: sorry , was editing the question . i have a codepen link there please have a look.

Comment: jquery not defined
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: you are using the jqery code, but issue is you are loading app code ahead of jquery code, also what is nature of issue you are having with `placeholder`?

Comment: jquery.placeholer is not defined. http://prntscr.com/9on8di

Comment: @BipuBajgai did you change the order and load jquery before app code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a fork of your codepen repo here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGRGvm

Seems to works after following changes:

1. Add Jquery to repo
2. Initialize

   ```
   jQuery('input, textarea').placeholder();
   ```

After you have included the placeholder function. The reason it gives you an error is because you are initializing using placeholder function, before its even loaded.

Or if you really want to put it on top/before placeholder func and since you are using jquery. Might as well, include the init function inside a document.ready.

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('input, textarea').placeholder();
 });
}(jQuery));
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: awesome! glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

put jQuery in your code..

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: that doesnot fix it .

Answer (score 0):

like I said in the comments, there are two mistakes in your code,

1. your are using jQuery before you are loading it, change the order, load jQuery first.
2. it is `$('input, textarea')` not `jQuery('input, textarea')`, basically change your code to:

   ```
   /* HTML5 placeholder jQuery plugin - v2.3.0
    * Copyright (c)2015 Mathias Bynens
    * 2015-11-13
    */
   !function(a){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],a):a("object"==typeof module&&module.exports?require("jquery"):jQuery)}(function(a){function b(b){var c={},d=/^jQuery\d+$/;return a.each(b.attributes,function(a,b){b.specified&&!d.test(b.name)&&(c[b.name]=b.value)}),c}function c(b,c){var d=this,f=a(this);if(d.value===f.attr(h?"placeholder-x":"placeholder")&&f.hasClass(n.customClass))if(d.value="",f.removeClass(n.customClass),f.data("placeholder-password")){if(f=f.hide().nextAll('input[type="password"]:first').show().attr("id",f.removeAttr("id").data("placeholder-id")),b===!0)return f[0].value=c,c;f.focus()}else d==e()&&d.select()}function d(d){var e,f=this,g=a(this),i=f.id;if(!d||"blur"!==d.type||!g.hasClass(n.customClass))if(""===f.value){if("password"===f.type){if(!g.data("placeholder-textinput")){try{e=g.clone().prop({type:"text"})}catch(j){e=a("<input>").attr(a.extend(b(this),{type:"text"}))}e.removeAttr("name").data({"placeholder-enabled":!0,"placeholder-password":g,"placeholder-id":i}).bind("focus.placeholder",c),g.data({"placeholder-textinput":e,"placeholder-id":i}).before(e)}f.value="",g=g.removeAttr("id").hide().prevAll('input[type="text"]:first').attr("id",g.data("placeholder-id")).show()}else{var k=g.data("placeholder-password");k&&(k[0].value="",g.attr("id",g.data("placeholder-id")).show().nextAll('input[type="password"]:last').hide().removeAttr("id"))}g.addClass(n.customClass),g[0].value=g.attr(h?"placeholder-x":"placeholder")}else g.removeClass(n.customClass)}function e(){try{return document.activeElement}catch(a){}}var f,g,h=!1,i="[object OperaMini]"===Object.prototype.toString.call(window.operamini),j="placeholder"in document.createElement("input")&&!i&&!h,k="placeholder"in document.createElement("textarea")&&!i&&!h,l=a.valHooks,m=a.propHooks,n={};j&&k?(g=a.fn.placeholder=function(){return this},g.input=!0,g.textarea=!0):(g=a.fn.placeholder=function(b){var e={customClass:"placeholder"};return n=a.extend({},e,b),this.filter((j?"textarea":":input")+"["+(h?"placeholder-x":"placeholder")+"]").not("."+n.customClass).not(":radio, :checkbox, :hidden").bind({"focus.placeholder":c,"blur.placeholder":d}).data("placeholder-enabled",!0).trigger("blur.placeholder")},g.input=j,g.textarea=k,f={get:function(b){var c=a(b),d=c.data("placeholder-password");return d?d[0].value:c.data("placeholder-enabled")&&c.hasClass(n.customClass)?"":b.value},set:function(b,f){var g,h,i=a(b);return""!==f&&(g=i.data("placeholder-textinput"),h=i.data("placeholder-password"),g?(c.call(g[0],!0,f)||(b.value=f),g[0].value=f):h&&(c.call(b,!0,f)||(h[0].value=f),b.value=f)),i.data("placeholder-enabled")?(""===f?(b.value=f,b!=e()&&d.call(b)):(i.hasClass(n.customClass)&&c.call(b),b.value=f),i):(b.value=f,i)}},j||(l.input=f,m.value=f),k||(l.textarea=f,m.value=f),a(function(){a(document).delegate("form","submit.placeholder",function(){var b=a("."+n.customClass,this).each(function(){c.call(this,!0,"")});setTimeout(function(){b.each(d)},10)})}),a(window).bind("beforeunload.placeholder",function(){var b=!0;try{"javascript:void(0)"===document.activeElement.toString()&&(b=!1)}catch(c){}b&&a("."+n.customClass).each(function(){this.value=""})}))});


   // Intializing placeholder 
   (function($) {
     $('input, textarea').placeholder();
   }(jQuery));
   ```